# Converting C uint8_t pointer + size combination to C++ iterators

Tags: c++, c, pointers, c++11, iterator

I have some C code that I want to encapsulate in C++ to make it easier to use.

The C code uses a `uint8_t*`/`size_t` pair to reference a piece of memory. Can I convert these to C++ iterators with something like `std::begin`/`std::end`? I know these functions don't accept pointers, but perhaps there's some other way. I want to avoid having to copy any data.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
void fn(uint8_t* ptr, size_t size) {
    auto begin = std::begin(...);
    auto end = std::end(...);

    // continue to use begin/end similar to std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator
}
```

The iterators should be usable with the standard library. Specifically I want to use it with `std::copy` and the `std::vector` constructor that takes iterators. I know I have other options to copy memory, but I'm looking for encapsulation in C++ types.

I also tried this, but apparently that is a private constructor. (Makes complete sense to me that I can't construct a vector iterator, but I'm just trying things.)

```
std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator begin(ptr);
```

I'd also prefer to avoid having to implement my own iterator types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
auto begin = ptr;
auto end = ptr+size;
```

will do the trick
(iterators are actually modelled after pointers)

Comment: This is what C++ (98) iterators were designed for, to be equal to using a pair of pointers in use.

Comment: Are they actually (convertible to) C++ iterators? I'm looking to pass them to std library functions that only take iterators.

Comment: std library functions are designed with that use in mind, just so all algorithms can be used together with c-style arrays too

Comment: I completely did not realise that. So it's much easier than I thought!

Comment: Moreover, std::vector is designed to be compatible with C arrays: if a function f accepts two parameters (pointer and size), you always can pass to this function pointer to the first element of a vector and size of the vector: f(&v[0], v.size()).

Comment: @DmitriyKuznetsov: And since C++11, `&v[0]` may be replaced by `v.data()`.

Comment: @molf: Actually, `std::vector<T>` being required to be contiguous storage, its iterator type can be implemented as a simple `T*`, and often is. The operations used on iterators are unary `*` (for dereferencing the iterator) and `++` (for advancing the iterator one position). More, `T*` models the most restrictive iterator concept, *RandomAccessIterator*, since it can advance and rewind an arbitrary number of positions in constant time, which permits automatically-selected better-performing implementations of some algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply define the function for example like:)

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
void fn( RandomAccessIterator begin, RandomAccessIterator end ) {

    // continue to use begin/end similar to std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator
}
```

and call it like

```
fn( ptr, ptr + size );
```

Of course you could choice any kind of the iterator that is more appropriate for the function.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, vector iterators are basically aliases of pointers:

```
typedef value_type* iterator;
typedef const value_type* const_iterator;
```

So, you can just write:

```
uint8_t* begin = ptr;
uint8_t* end = ptr + size;
```

All operators (`++`, `*`) will work in the same way.

Comment: Often they are wrapped, and in debug checked.